# Batch file closes after >1 input

Tags: batch-file

I'm fairly new to programming, however I've done a fair bit of Web Development in the past. I've had a little idea for my first program, which consists of a Command Prompt UI asking you if you want to close programs, after shutting down some background tasks I personally don't care for.

Here's the code so far:

```
:start
set /p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto yes
if %cho%==y goto yes
if %cho%==n goto eof
if %cho%==N goto eof

:yes
echo If you need help type "hlp". If you don't type "cont". To close type 
"end"
set /p "yesInput=>"
if %yesInput%=hlp goto hlp
if %yesInput%=cont goto cont
if %yesInput%=end goto end

:hlp

TASKLIST
echo To Return type "cont"
set /p "hlpInput"
if %hlpInput%=cont goto cont
if else echo Error
:cont


:end
goto eof
```

EDIT: The background tasks are GoogleCrashHandler64, and GoogleCrashHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if %yesInput%=hlp goto hlp
```

the comparison operator is `==`, not `=` (repeated many times)

(btw - `if /i ...` means case-insensitive)

```
set /p "hlpInput"
```

compare this to the other `set /p` commands.

```
if else echo Error
```

I gather your intention is "otherwise". If the prior test was successful, execution will be transferred to the label as instructed. Therefore if we rech this instruction, we must have the condition"otherwise" so there's no need to test it.

`if` is very simple-minded in batch. It's not like a `case` statement. From the prompt, see if /?` for documentation. The general format is

if *booleancondition* (dothis) else (dothat)

where the parentheses are only required if there is an `else` condition or if *dothis* or *dothat* are multi-line instructions (known as a `code block`). Also, the opening `(` must beon the same physical line as the `if` and the `) else (` must all be on one physical line.

When you're testing input from the keyboard, the user may enter a string that contains spaces or commas. It's there fore safer (but not foolproof) to use the syntax

```
if "string"=="another string" ...
```

as the quotes cause the value to be interpreted as a single 'token'

Please note that batch siply executes instructions serially until it reaches a `goto` or end-of-file (but it can be diverted by a `call`). Labels are simply markers - they do not indicate "end of procedure" as in some other languages. The consequence is that unless you insert a specific `goto` instruction, batch will simply careen through labels and execute any instructions it finds.

The special instruction `goto :eof` will go to end-of-file. Note that the colon here is *required*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, rather than criticism.

Comment: Batch is a very civilised area of the SO jungle.